# How can I get acces to my BackEnd API from a distant machine

Tags: c#, rest, api, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get acces (I mean POSTing,GETing...) to my backend API written using asp.net Core and registred in the machine which has the following ip address (for example : **192.168.1.80**) from a machine that has the followingg ip address (for ex: 192.168.1.71), When I run my app using the following launchSettings.json :

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/ServerMonitoringApi",
      "sslPort": 0
    },
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:9999",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/Alerting",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "ServerMonitoringApi": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/Alerting",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:9999;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

I can use it if I stay in the same machine i.e : https://localhost:9999, but when I try to get the data from the distant machine where I use https://192.168.1.80:9999 it doesnt work for me, do I need to configure something? Or allow the acces to my port(9999).
I'm a newbie be gentel, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Just to clarify, are they in the same network or is your computer that's hosting your API off-site?

Comment: They are in the same Network and same cluster

Comment: Ah ok. Then the problem is easier, your ASP.NET/ IIS isn't listening on the IP address of the machine, instead it's listening on `localhost`, so only connection trying to connect to `localhost` will be accepted. You can add the application URL (either in code in `Program.cs` or in your config) of where the server is hosted and it should work. Note: binding to `localhost` will not accept remote connections, but binding to your local IP will accept remote connections and connections going to `localhost`

Comment: I did as @bmartins said but I didnt work for me maybe Iv missed something

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify more urls when building the `WebHost` in `Program.cs`, otherwise Kestrel isn't going to listen outside localhost.

```cs
var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseUrls("http://....") // url of your server using server name or IP
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
```

Of course, do not forget to remove that line when going into production.

Comment: My mistake, I wrote too quickly. You should enter the url of your server like `http://<name of server>:5000` or `http://<ip of server>:5000`

Comment: If your application is kestrel facing then I believe you can bind to `0.0.0.0` rather than explicitly having to specify the private IP address (that might get reassigned by DHCP). If its IIS facing then that's a different story.

Comment: I wrote this : .`ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder
                    .UseUrls("http://192.168.1.80:9999")
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
                });`, but it still didnt work :/

Comment: I didnt work its say that Iit couldnt get any result (m using Postman for the test btw)